# HTML Table row (tr): How to set the height fixed, equals to the biggest height element

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table in my html page. Inside, I have trs and tds.

My goal is to set somehow the height of each tr to be the same size as the height of the biggest tr.

For example:

I have 3 trs: In each tr i can have an image. In the first one, there is no image, in the second one, the image is 20px height and in the third one is 30px height. My goal is to heve the 3 trs to be 30px height = aligned to the height of the biggest image.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for that. Or set a height in advance that you know is big enough to contain any row.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, I know allready the height of the biggest image, so I could do it with that?

Comment: Set the `tr` height to that image's height in your CSS file.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you please answer this question so i will be able to confirm and close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the largest `<tr>` height in advance, set the height for all `tr`s to it in your CSS file:

```
tr {
   height: <INSERT-HEIGHT-HERE>px;
}
```